# How does this vector field does make sense? ($V(x) = \frac x {\|x\|}$).

Tags: differential-geometry

In my learning of differential geometry, I started to learn about vector fields. I am going to use the point of view of derivatives.

In this picture, let us consider $\mathbb R^n$ as a manifold and $X$ a vector field defined on $\mathbb R^n\backslash\{0\}$ by:
$$
X(p) = \frac{p}{\|p\|}
$$

However, until now, I only encountered vector fields of the form $X(p) = X^i(p) \left. \dfrac{\partial}{\partial  x^i}\right|_{p}$. In the previous expression, I don't understand how can I consider $X$ as a derivative?

Moreover, how to determine the flow of $X$?

EDIT: I still have some trouble understanding this.

I read that the flow is given by
$$
\phi^t(p) = p + t\frac{p}{\|p\|}
$$

However, according to the comments, $X(\gamma(t)) = \frac{\gamma_i(t)}{\|\gamma(t)\|} \left. \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right|_{\gamma(t)} = \gamma'_i(t)\left. \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right|_{\gamma(t)}$. I don't get why we get the previous form

Comment: The "issue" with $\mathbb{R}^n$ is that a vector field can be seen as a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. The vector field you wrote is just $$X(p) = \frac{p^i}{||p||} \left. \partial_i \right|_p, $$ where $p = (p^1, \cdots, p^n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: For every vector in this field it assigns the unit vector in the same direction. You can think of this as every circle centered at zero flowing at a constant rate away from the origin.

Comment: Thank you both, that's clear!

Comment: @C_M I added some question to be sure to understand well